# Typed Tasks in Julia

Tags: julia

In many other languages one can make a generic asynchronous iterable type, like `Observable<T>` in Rx variants, `chan T` in Go.

Julia's coroutine abstraction `Task` is a comparable construct which can pass objects between (lightweight) threads. Does Julia have a method to annotate the type of those objects?

I would like to make a function that accepts a `Task` as its parameter and be able to express the type of objects that the task emits. For example, if `Task` were a generic type, I would imagine:

```
function foo(socket::Task{String})
    for word in socket
         println(word)
    end
end
```

More generally, is there an abstract type for objects that are iterable using `for` (or other methods using `start`/`next`/`done`) so that I can annotate in function signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is such a thing at this time.

On your "more general" question, there isn't such a thing yet, but its something people want. [Here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6975) is an issue with people discussing ideas and possibilities.